# c++ program crash when inputing text file into array

Tags: c++

i am new at c++, i am trying to make a program that can input a matriks from ftitikberat.txt with this format: 

id[...] -> matriks id

row[id[...]] -> number of matriks rows

coloumns[id[...]] -> number of matriks coloumns

matriks[id[...]] [row[id[...]]] [col[id[...]]] -> matriks

name[id[...]] -> matriks name

the program can be compiled, but when i try to input ftitikberat.txt its always crash

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
int row[1000]; 
int col[1000];
int matriks[1000][4][4];
int id[1000];
int i,j,k;
string name[1000];
ifstream ifile("ftitikberat.txt");
for(i=1; i<=1000; i++)  
{
    ifile>>id[i]>>name[i]>>row[i]>>col[i];
    for(j=1; j<=row[id[i]]; j++)
    {
        for(k=1; k<=col[id[i]]; k++)
        {
            ifile>>matriks[id[i]][j][k];
        }
    }
}
ifile.close();
```

and for the text:

> 1 null 1 1 0
>   
> 2 null 1 1 0
>   
> 3 null 1 1 0
>   
> 4 null 1 1 0
>   
> .
>   
> . //until
>   
> .
>   
> 998 null 1 1 0
>   
> 999 null 1 1 0
>   
> 1000 null 1 1 0

i have tried to change the text to:

...

998 null 1 1 0 1

...

and when i try to compile and run it, the program work just fine, except i cant use id 999 and 1000 because it just messed up, same when i tried to change the text at id 997 (997 null 1 1 0 1) and program didn't crash but i cant use id 998,999,1000

i have also tried to change maximal array one by one, and the program didn't crash when i change maximal array of (id and name) from 1000 to 1001, but i dont know why its work

can somebody please explain me why the program (before i changing text/maximal array) didn't work? i staring at this simple program like hours, but still don't know where the problem is :')

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array indexes go from `0` to `size-1`, not from `1` to `size`. So you're accessing outside the arrays when you do:

```
for(i=1; i<=1000; i++)
```

it should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
```

Your other loops should also start from `0` and use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: thank, i really forgot about that, so when i type arrays[1000] it goes from 0-999 right?

Comment: That's correct. This is a basic feature of almost all programming languages, you need to get used to it.